# ERROR 1064:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: stored-procedures, mariadb

I have a Sql File named procedure.sql with a procedure.
Maria DB Version: Server version: 10.0.29-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Ubuntu 16.04

But I am getting ERROR AS Follows:

```
>mysql -u root -p XXX < /home/azure/Downloads/procedure.sql 
>Enter password: 
>ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '();
>USE XXX;
>CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE XXX.updateDoc_StorageID () 
>BEGIN' at line 1
```

Can anyone help me please?

procedure.sql Code:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS XXX.updateDoc_StorageID;
USE XXX;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE XXX.updateDoc_StorageID () 
BEGIN
    DECLARE myTransacID INT DEFAULT 0; 
    DECLARE myTransProductId INT DEFAULT 0; 
    DECLARE myDocStoreID VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT '0'; 
    DECLARE my_count INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE trans_csr CURSOR FOR SELECT 1,2 FROM MainTable ORDER BY TransactionID;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET my_count=1;
    SET my_count=0;
    OPEN trans_csr;
        trans_loop:LOOP
            FETCH trans_csr INTO myTransacID,myTransProductId;
          IF my_count=1 THEN
                   LEAVE trans_loop;
                END IF;
                If(myTransProductId=8)
                   then
                   if exists(....)
                   then
                           .......
                   end if;
                   elseif (myTransProductId=11) 
                   then
                   if exists(........)
                   then
                           .......
                   END IF;
            END IF;
        END LOOP trans_loop;
    CLOSE trans_csr;
    SET my_count=0;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

The Reference I got is from :
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-procedure/

Comment: What code is in your procedure.sql? We don't have a glass ball here:)

Comment: Added a piece only, unable to provide the whole code at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is not for `CREATE PROCEDURE`, it's for the preceding `DROP PROCEDURE`, you shouldn't have brackets there.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS XXX.updateDoc_StorageID;
```

The second error follows, since the procedure hasn't been dropped, it still exists.

Also, fix the delimiters -- if you set `$$` at the start, then every further query should end with `$$`, not with semicolon.

Comment: After Modifying it as you recommends: The Error is:   ERROR 1221 (HY000) at line 2: Incorrect usage of OR REPLACE and TRIGGERS / SP / EVENT

Comment: `OR REPLACE` clause for procedures was introduced in 10.1, while you're using 10.0. Lose it, you don't need it anyway since you're dropping the procedure first. And in the current snippet, you still haven't fixed delimiters, you simply replaced `$$` with `//`, but the same remark still applies -- if you set a non-semicolon as a delimiter, you should actually use it for following statements.

Comment: I done with the syntax as given in the The Reference I got from : 
<https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-procedure/>
So, please help giving the right syntax in code

Comment: Yes, and this page specifically mentions that `OR REPLACE` was introduced in 10.1.3, while you are using 10.0. As I said, remove `OR REPLACE` clause from your `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

Comment: The Drop Statement
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS GTX_CC.updateDoc_StorageID;
is not working. While Running it is still giving error:|
    ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 47: You have an error in your SQL 
    syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server 
    version for the right syntax to use near 'ERROR 1304 (42000): 
    PROCEDURE updateDoc_StorageID already exists

Answer (score 0):

The right syntax for version 10.0.x StoredProcedure will be:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS XXX.updateDoc_StorageID;
USE XXX;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE XXX.updateDoc_StorageID () 
BEGIN
    DECLARE myTransacID INT DEFAULT 0; 
    DECLARE myTransProductId INT DEFAULT 0; 
    DECLARE myDocStoreID VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT '0'; 
    DECLARE my_count INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE trans_csr CURSOR FOR SELECT 1,2 FROM MainTable ORDER BY TransactionID;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET my_count=1;
    SET my_count=0;
    OPEN trans_csr;
        trans_loop:LOOP
            FETCH trans_csr INTO myTransacID,myTransProductId;
          IF my_count=1 THEN
                   LEAVE trans_loop;
                END IF;
                If(myTransProductId=8)
                   then
                   if exists(....)
                   then
                           .......
                   end if;
                   elseif (myTransProductId=11) 
                   then
                   if exists(........)
                   then
                           .......
                   END IF;
            END IF;
        END LOOP trans_loop;
    CLOSE trans_csr;
    SET my_count=0;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```